# onClick event of fragmentActivity's view inside of Fragment class?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have included a common layout inside of `FragmentActivity`.I want to fire onclick event of common layout ToggleButton, inside of fragment class.How can I achieve this?

```
ToggleButton tbMainLocation = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(
                R.id.tbMainLocation);
```

but `tbMainLocation` always return `nullpointerexception`

**commonlayout:**

**layout_include.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlMainLivTopBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cyan"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMainBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="&lt;"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMainBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/actv_edt_search_tag_feed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_edittext"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Search by tag"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <requestFocus />
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMainTagneme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMainExpertName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <!--
         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        androImid:background="@drawable/notification" />
        -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMainExpertEarnByFlight"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/plane_normal"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <!--
             <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMainLocation"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgMainSearch"
            android:background="@drawable/location"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        -->

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tbMainLocation"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/location_selector"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llExpertfragmentChooseDistance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_liv_top_bar"
        android:background="@color/light_cyan"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_choose_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:maxWidth="60dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/choose_distance"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_expert_earn_by_walk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/walk_normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_cycle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
            android:background="@color/cyan_line"
            android:maxHeight="6dp"
            android:minWidth="40dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_expert_earn_by_cycle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cycle_normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_bike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
            android:background="@color/cyan_line"
            android:maxHeight="6dp"
            android:minWidth="40dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_expert_earn_by_bike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/car_normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_train"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
            android:background="@color/cyan_line"
            android:maxHeight="6dp"
            android:minWidth="40dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_expert_earn_by_flight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/plane_normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragmentactivity.xml**

```
<com.liv.slidingmenu.layout.MainLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- This holds our menu -->

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ll_top_menu_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#6d6d6d"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- This acts as Actionbar -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_prof_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#434242" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rr_img_detail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_prof"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/profile_image" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_expt_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/img_leve"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_prof"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_level"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_expt_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_prof"
                    android:background="@drawable/level_background"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#d2d2d2" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_prof_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview_menu_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="#292929"
                android:dividerHeight="0.1dip" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_topbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/topbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/layout_include" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_topbar" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontents"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <!-- android:id="@android:id/tabs" -->

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#f9f9f9"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </RelativeLayout>

</com.liv.slidingmenu.layout.MainLayout>
```

Comment: Initilaize in `onActivityCreated`. `getView()` returns null. Does the view belong to the fragment layout?

Comment: @Raghunandan, The view belongs to common layout which is included in FragmentActivity 's layout as   <include
                android:id="@+id/topbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/layout_include" />

Comment: then use `getActivity().findViewById(R.id....)`.

Comment: I will try and update you.

Comment: Is the problem that you can't fire the on click or that the fragment doesn't find the toggle button?

Comment: @Raghunandan,Your final answer worked as I expected.Thank u so much.

Comment: @Raghunandan,You can add this as a answer , I will accept it.

Comment: ok i just answered the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access views that belong to the activity layout you can use

```
 getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewid);
```

Make sure the fragment is attached to the activity and `getActivity()` does not return null.

Quoting docs

> The fragment can access the Activity instance with getActivity() and
>   easily perform tasks such as find a view in the activity layout

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html